# different results of xsl transformation using java transformer and command line processor

Tags: java, xml, xslt

Applying XSL in Java works on some data samples, but produces an empty result on others, where a command line processor still produces a valid result.
Below is an example where i see the difference.
given an XSL and an XML listed below, the command line:

```
saxonb-xslt -s:metsmods_test3.xml -xsl:metsmods2.xsl
```

returns:

```
  Warning: at xsl:stylesheet on line 5 column 61 of metsmods2.xsl:
  Running an XSLT 1.0 stylesheet with an XSLT 2.0 processor

        main_label:Wachsende Häuser aus lebenden Bäumen entstehend
        identifier:urn:nbn:de:kobv:83-goobi-3255500
        main_label:II. Teil. Art und Verwendung der Naturbauten.
        identifier:urn:nbn:de:kobv:83-goobi-3255762
        main_label:III. Teil. Erörterung sonstiger Punkte.
        identifier:urn:nbn:de:kobv:83-goobi-3255929
        main_label:
        identifier:urn:nbn:de:kobv:83-goobi-3256094
        main_label:
        identifier:urn:nbn:de:kobv:83-goobi-3256100
        identifier.kobv:990006350260302884
        title:Wachsende Häuser aus lebenden Bäumen entstehend
        title:Wachsende Häuser aus lebenden Bäumen entstehend
```

But the java tranformer snipplet (taken from https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/xml/xpath/xpath-xslt-tutorial/ and listed below) produces no output on the same files  saxonb-xslt does. 
I assume this has to do with namespaces or access to DTD's, which the command line processor and the chosen transformer handle differently.
but what exactly? why no exceptions while processing in Java?

code:

```
public class Main {

private static Document document;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

    File xml = new File("/home/peter/1stax/src/metsmods_test3.xml");
    File xsl = new File("/home/peter/1stax/src/metsmods2.xsl");


    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    document = builder.parse(xml);

    // Use a Transformer for output
    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    StreamSource style = new StreamSource(xsl);
    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer(style);

    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
    transformer.transform(source, result);
}
```

}

xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:mets="http://www.loc.gov/METS/"
                xmlns:mods="http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3"
                xmlns:goobi="http://meta.goobi.org/v1.5.1/">

    <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no" encoding="utf-8"/>

    <xsl:variable name="dmdsec_id">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="/mets:mets/mets:structMap[@TYPE='LOGICAL']/mets:div/@DMDID">
                <xsl:value-of select="/mets:mets/mets:structMap[@TYPE='LOGICAL']/mets:div/@DMDID"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="/mets:mets/mets:structMap[@TYPE='LOGICAL']/mets:div/mets:div/@DMDID">
                        <xsl:value-of select="/mets:mets/mets:structMap[@TYPE='LOGICAL']/mets:div/mets:div/@DMDID"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:text>DMDLOG_0000</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/">

        <xsl:for-each select="//mets:structMap[@TYPE='LOGICAL']/mets:div">
            main_label:<xsl:value-of select="@LABEL"/>
            identifier:<xsl:value-of select="@CONTENTIDS"/>
        </xsl:for-each>

        <xsl:for-each select="//mets:dmdSec[@ID=$dmdsec_id]/mets:mdWrap/mets:xmlData/mods:mods/mods:identifier">
            identifier.<xsl:value-of select="@type"/>:<xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>

        <xsl:for-each select="//mets:dmdSec[@ID=$dmdsec_id]/mets:mdWrap/mets:xmlData/mods:mods/mods:recordInfo/mods:recordIdentifier">
            identifier.<xsl:value-of select="@source"/>:<xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>

        <xsl:for-each select="//mets:dmdSec[@ID=$dmdsec_id]/mets:mdWrap/mets:xmlData/mods:mods/mods:titleInfo/mods:title">
            title:<xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>


    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

xml data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mets:mets OBJID="" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3 http://www.loc.gov/standards/mods/v3/mods-3-5.xsd http://www.loc.gov/METS/ http://www.loc.gov/standards/mets/mets.xsd http://www.loc.gov/standards/premis/ http://www.loc.gov/standards/premis/v2/premis-v2-0.xsd http://www.loc.gov/standards/mix/ http://www.loc.gov/standards/mix/mix.xsd" xmlns:mets="http://www.loc.gov/METS/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <mets:metsHdr CREATEDATE="2018-02-27T12:37:35Z">
      <mets:agent OTHERTYPE="SOFTWARE" ROLE="CREATOR" TYPE="OTHER">
         <mets:name>Goobi - ugh-3.0-ugh-2.0.0-29-g3b6efe1 - 21−December−2016</mets:name>
         <mets:note>Goobi</mets:note>
      </mets:agent>
   </mets:metsHdr>
   <mets:dmdSec ID="DMDLOG_0000">
      <mets:mdWrap MDTYPE="MODS">
         <mets:xmlData>
            <mods:mods xmlns:mods="http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3">
               <mods:titleInfo>
                  <mods:title>Wachsende Häuser aus lebenden Bäumen entstehend</mods:title>
               </mods:titleInfo>
               <mods:titleInfo type="uniform">
                  <mods:title>Wachsende Häuser aus lebenden Bäumen entstehend</mods:title>
               </mods:titleInfo>
               <mods:recordInfo>
                  <mods:recordIdentifier source="kobv">990006350260302884</mods:recordIdentifier>
               </mods:recordInfo>
               <mods:classification authority="ivdcc">Deutsche Gartenbaubibliothek#Monographien#Gartenbau</mods:classification>
               <mods:classification authority="ivdcc">Zentralbibliothek#Monographien#Technik, Architektur, Bauwesen</mods:classification>
               <mods:language>
                  <mods:languageTerm authority="iso639-2b" type="code">ger</mods:languageTerm>
               </mods:language>
               <mods:originInfo>
                  <mods:dateIssued encoding="w3cdtf" keyDate="yes">[1926]</mods:dateIssued>
               </mods:originInfo>
               <mods:accessCondition type="use and reproduction">https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/mark/1.0/</mods:accessCondition>
               <mods:physicalDescription>
                  <mods:extent>320 Seiten</mods:extent>
                  <mods:digitalOrigin>reformatted digital</mods:digitalOrigin>
               </mods:physicalDescription>
               <mods:location>
                  <mods:shelfLocator>8Af6500</mods:shelfLocator>
                  <mods:physicalLocation>Universitätsbibliothek der Technischen Universität Berlin</mods:physicalLocation>
               </mods:location>
               <mods:name authority="gnd" authorityURI="http://d-nb.info/gnd/" type="personal" valueURI="http://d-nb.info/gnd/1065837569">
                  <mods:role>
                     <mods:roleTerm authority="marcrelator" type="code">aut</mods:roleTerm>
                  </mods:role>
                  <mods:namePart type="family">Wiechula</mods:namePart>
                  <mods:namePart type="given">Arthur</mods:namePart>
                  <mods:displayForm>Wiechula, Arthur</mods:displayForm>
               </mods:name>
               <mods:originInfo>
                  <mods:place>
                     <mods:placeTerm type="text">Berlin</mods:placeTerm>
                  </mods:place>
                  <mods:dateCaptured encoding="w3cdtf">2018</mods:dateCaptured>
                  <mods:publisher>Universitätsbibliothek der Technischen Universität Berlin</mods:publisher>
                  <mods:edition>[Electronic ed.]</mods:edition>
               </mods:originInfo>
            </mods:mods>
         </mets:xmlData>
      </mets:mdWrap>
   </mets:dmdSec>

   <mets:fileSec>
      <mets:fileGrp USE="PRESENTATION">
         <mets:file ID="FILE_0001_PRESENTATION" MIMETYPE="image/tif">
            <mets:FLocat LOCTYPE="URL" xlink:href="file:///opt/digiverso/viewer/media/990006350260302884/wiecwach_990006350260302884_0001.tif" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"/>
         </mets:file>
         <mets:file ID="FILE_0002_PRESENTATION" MIMETYPE="image/tif">
            <mets:FLocat LOCTYPE="URL" xlink:href="file:///opt/digiverso/viewer/media/990006350260302884/wiecwach_990006350260302884_0002.tif" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"/>
         </mets:file>
         <mets:file ID="FILE_0003_PRESENTATION" MIMETYPE="image/tif">
            <mets:FLocat LOCTYPE="URL" xlink:href="file:///opt/digiverso/viewer/media/990006350260302884/wiecwach_990006350260302884_0003.tif" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"/>
         </mets:file>
         <mets:file ID="FILE_0004_PRESENTATION" MIMETYPE="image/tif">
            <mets:FLocat LOCTYPE="URL" xlink:href="file:///opt/digiverso/viewer/media/990006350260302884/wiecwach_990006350260302884_0004.tif" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"/>
         </mets:file>
         <mets:file ID="FILE_0005_PRESENTATION" MIMETYPE="image/tif">
            <mets:FLocat LOCTYPE="URL" xlink:href="file:///opt/digiverso/viewer/media/990006350260302884/wiecwach_990006350260302884_0005.tif" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"/>
         </mets:file>
      </mets:fileGrp>
   </mets:fileSec>
   <mets:structMap TYPE="LOGICAL">
      <mets:div ADMID="AMD" CONTENTIDS="urn:nbn:de:kobv:83-goobi-3255500" DMDID="DMDLOG_0000" ID="LOG_0000" LABEL="Wachsende Häuser aus lebenden Bäumen entstehend" TYPE="Monograph">
         <mets:div CONTENTIDS="urn:nbn:de:kobv:83-goobi-3255512" ID="LOG_0001" TYPE="Cover"/>
         <mets:div CONTENTIDS="urn:nbn:de:kobv:83-goobi-3255526" ID="LOG_0002" TYPE="TitlePage"/>
         <mets:div CONTENTIDS="urn:nbn:de:kobv:83-goobi-3255538" DMDID="DMDLOG_0003" ID="LOG_0003" LABEL="Vorwort." TYPE="Preface"/>
         <mets:div CONTENTIDS="urn:nbn:de:kobv:83-goobi-3255549" DMDID="DMDLOG_0004" ID="LOG_0004" LABEL="Inhalts-Verzeichnis." TYPE="TableOfContents"/>
         <mets:div CONTENTIDS="urn:nbn:de:kobv:83-goobi-3255550" DMDID="DMDLOG_0005" ID="LOG_0005" LABEL="Verzeichnis der Abbildungen." TYPE="ListOfIllustrations"/>
         <mets:div CONTENTIDS="urn:nbn:de:kobv:83-goobi-3255567" DMDID="DMDLOG_0006" ID="LOG_0006" LABEL="Stichwörterverzeichnis." TYPE="OtherDocStrct"/>
         </mets:div>
         <mets:div CONTENTIDS="urn:nbn:de:kobv:83-goobi-3255762" DMDID="DMDLOG_0026" ID="LOG_0026" LABEL="II. Teil. Art und Verwendung der Naturbauten." TYPE="Chapter">
            <mets:div CONTENTIDS="urn:nbn:de:kobv:83-goobi-3255774" DMDID="DMDLOG_0027" ID="LOG_0027" LABEL="18. Zäune." TYPE="Chapter"/>
            <mets:div CONTENTIDS="urn:nbn:de:kobv:83-goobi-3255789" DMDID="DMDLOG_0028" ID="LOG_0028" LABEL="19. Einfache Häuser." TYPE="Chapter"/>
         </mets:div>
         <mets:div CONTENTIDS="urn:nbn:de:kobv:83-goobi-3255929" DMDID="DMDLOG_0042" ID="LOG_0042" LABEL="III. Teil. Erörterung sonstiger Punkte." TYPE="Chapter">
            <mets:div CONTENTIDS="urn:nbn:de:kobv:83-goobi-3255936" DMDID="DMDLOG_0043" ID="LOG_0043" LABEL="33. Die Entstehungsdauer der Naturbauwerke." TYPE="Chapter"/>
            <mets:div CONTENTIDS="urn:nbn:de:kobv:83-goobi-3255949" DMDID="DMDLOG_0044" ID="LOG_0044" LABEL="34. Das Lebensalter der Naturbauwerke." TYPE="Chapter"/>
         </mets:div>
         <mets:div CONTENTIDS="urn:nbn:de:kobv:83-goobi-3256094" ID="LOG_0059" TYPE="Cover"/>
         <mets:div CONTENTIDS="urn:nbn:de:kobv:83-goobi-3256100" ID="LOG_0060" TYPE="ColorChart"/>
   </mets:structMap>
   <mets:structMap TYPE="PHYSICAL">
      <mets:div ID="PHYS_0000" TYPE="physSequence">
         <mets:div CONTENTIDS="urn:nbn:de:kobv:83-goobi-3256112" ID="PHYS_0001" ORDER="1" ORDERLABEL=" - " TYPE="page">
            <mets:fptr FILEID="FILE_0001_PRESENTATION"/>
            <mets:fptr FILEID="FILE_0001_MIN"/>
            <mets:fptr FILEID="FILE_0001_DEFAULT"/>
            <mets:fptr FILEID="FILE_0001_MAX"/>
            <mets:fptr FILEID="FILE_0001_THUMBS"/>
         </mets:div>
         <mets:div CONTENTIDS="urn:nbn:de:kobv:83-goobi-3256122" ID="PHYS_0002" ORDER="2" ORDERLABEL=" - " TYPE="page">
            <mets:fptr FILEID="FILE_0002_PRESENTATION"/>
            <mets:fptr FILEID="FILE_0002_MIN"/>
            <mets:fptr FILEID="FILE_0002_DEFAULT"/>
            <mets:fptr FILEID="FILE_0002_MAX"/>
            <mets:fptr FILEID="FILE_0002_THUMBS"/>
         </mets:div>
         <mets:div CONTENTIDS="urn:nbn:de:kobv:83-goobi-3256138" ID="PHYS_0003" ORDER="3" ORDERLABEL=" - " TYPE="page">
            <mets:fptr FILEID="FILE_0003_PRESENTATION"/>
            <mets:fptr FILEID="FILE_0003_MIN"/>
            <mets:fptr FILEID="FILE_0003_DEFAULT"/>
            <mets:fptr FILEID="FILE_0003_MAX"/>
            <mets:fptr FILEID="FILE_0003_THUMBS"/>
         </mets:div>
      </mets:div>
   </mets:structMap>
   <mets:structLink>
      <mets:smLink xlink:to="PHYS_0001" xlink:from="LOG_0000" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"/>
      <mets:smLink xlink:to="PHYS_0002" xlink:from="LOG_0000" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"/>
      <mets:smLink xlink:to="PHYS_0003" xlink:from="LOG_0000" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"/>
      <mets:smLink xlink:to="PHYS_0004" xlink:from="LOG_0000" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"/>
      <mets:smLink xlink:to="PHYS_0005" xlink:from="LOG_0000" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"/>
      <mets:smLink xlink:to="PHYS_0006" xlink:from="LOG_0000" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"/>
   </mets:structLink>
</mets:mets>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you explicitly use a namespace aware DocumentBuilderFactory if you want to process XML and XSLT with Java as otherwise you won't get a meaningful result, XSLT itself is XML depending on namespaces and any XML input it uses is also better processed with namespace support.

Of course to simply use XML from a file as the input you don't need a DocumentBuilder and a DOMSource, you can use a StreamSource as well where then the XSLT processor takes care of processing the input in a namespace aware mode.

Answer (score 3):

Following the answer by Martin Honnen i have removed the completely unnecessary "parse to DOM" part from the Snipplet form "javacodegeeks" i was using (which must have been messing up the namespaces) and went the way of the least resistance, just replacing it by a StreamSource. and it works now!
here is the new code:

```
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import java.io.File;


public class Main {

    private static Document document;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

        File xml = new File("/home/peter/1stax/src/metsmods_test3.xml");
        File xsl = new File("/home/peter/1stax/src/metsmods2.xsl");
        // Use a Transformer for output
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        StreamSource style = new StreamSource(xsl);
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer(style);

        StreamSource source = new StreamSource (xml);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
        transformer.transform(source, result);
     }
}
```